# Apache2 keeps redirecting

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, configuration

I trying to keep the user on the url www.mydomain.de, but Apache uses a 301 Permament Redirect to mydomain.de .How can I prevent this?

httpd.include for the vhost

```
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80>
    ServerName   mydomain.de:80
    ServerAlias   www.mydomain.de
    UseCanonicalName off
    SuexecUserGroup         mydomain psacln
    ServerAdmin  "info@mydomain.de"
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.de/httpdocs
</VirtualHost>
```

DNS Settings

```
    ; *** This file is automatically generated by Plesk ***
    $TTL    86400

    @       IN      SOA     ns.mydomain.de. info.mydomain.de. (
                            1246541440      ; Serial
                            10800   ; Refresh
                            3600    ; Retry
                            604800  ; Expire
                            360 )   ; Minimum

    mydomain.de.           IN NS   ns.mydomain.de.
    mydomain.de.              IN NS   ns2.hans.hosteurope.de.
    ns.mydomain.de.                IN A    92.51.134.24
    mydomain.de.           IN A    92.51.134.24
    webmail.mydomain.de.           IN A    92.51.134.24
    mail.mydomain.de.              IN A    92.51.134.24
    science.mydomain.de.           IN A    92.51.134.24
    test.mydomain.de.              IN A    92.51.134.24
    testing.mydomain.de.           IN A    92.51.134.24
    ftp.mydomain.de.               IN CNAME        mydomain.de.
    www.mydomain.de.               IN CNAME        mydomain.de.
    *.webmail.mydomain.de.                 IN CNAME        mydomain.de.
    mydomain.de.           IN MX  10 mail.mydomain.de.
    mydomain.de.           IN TXT  "v=spf1 +a +mx -all"
```

Any Ideas, why this is happening? Thanks!

Edit:
Thanks Chaos for your Input (cannot vote your answer up yet) , but unfortunately, 
it still doesn't work.

Fiddler2 Output

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: de
UA-CPU: x86
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 4.0.20506; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)
Host: www.mydomain.de
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive


HTTP/1.0 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Thu, 02 Jul 2009 18:38:34 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.8 (Ubuntu) DAV/2 SVN/1.5.1 mod_ssl/2.2.8 OpenSSL/0.9.8g mod_python/3.3.1 Python/2.5.2 PHP/5.2.10 mod_perl/2.0.3 Perl/v5.8.8
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.10
X-Pingback: http://mydomain.de/xmlrpc.php
Location: http://mydomain.de/
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Cache: MISS from dezntpx01.computacenter.de
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from dezntpx01.computacenter.de:8081
X-Cache: MISS from dezntpx03.computacenter.de
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from dezntpx03.computacenter.de:8081
Via: 1.0 dezntpx01.computacenter.de:8081 (squid/2.7.STABLE5), 1.0 dezntpx03.computacenter.de:8081 (squid/2.7.STABLE5)
Connection: keep-alive
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: Can you please provide some more information. What is the contents of /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.de/httpdocs? Is there any .htaccess files?

Comment: I removed all the .htaccess files in the httpdocs dir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first thing is that this:

```
ServerName   mydomain.de:80
ServerAlias   www.mydomain.de
```

needs to be this:

```
ServerName    www.mydomain.de
ServerAlias   mydomain.de
```

`UseCanonicalName` should probably be on, too.  If you want to keep them on one version of the site, it's helping you, not hurting you.

**Edit**: Okay, the problem is that your Apache server isn't even controlling the behavior you're seeing; the proxy you're talking to is.  Why it's deciding to throw a 301 redirect isn't clear, but possibly it may be because `www.mydomain.de` is a `CNAME` record.  I'd try making it an `A` record.

It may also take some arbitrary amount of time for the proxy to notice anything you're doing and adjust its behavior.  For all I know, it could also have actual configured rules on it that are telling it to strip the `www` from your domain.

Comment: I removed several lines because of the apache modules. It's closed correctly.

Comment: It's nothing to do with the CNAME, apache doesn't know or care about that. The www prefix being on the server alias rather than the server name would not cause apache to magically send 301 moved.

Comment: Okay, that's great, but please now go back and read what I actually wrote.  The 301 isn't being generated by Apache, it's being generated by a proxy, and what rules it uses to determine when it should send one are another matter entirely from Apache's.